# Android XML. What is the purpose of the star in the ID string?

Tags: android

In some sources I see such declarations

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_display_groups"
    android:icon="@*android:drawable/ic_menu_allfriends"
    android:title="@string/menu_displayGroup" />
```

Notice the *

```
@*android:
```

It seems to give access to internal resources. But would like to know for sure.

Also curious, if it is safe to build application with such declarations using Android 2.2 SDK, and run it on 1.5.

Comment: It's giving error in my code if i use start id seekbar , can u please tell any solution for that ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are correct, it gives access to internal resources for platform apps. It is **NOT** safe to build apps with such declarations unless you are building a bundled app within a full system image.

Internal resources can (and do) change/get removed not only from platform version to platform version, but also from device to device or device version to device version.